# Maven - Sharing libraries between projects

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, maven-2, maven-3, ear

I'm working on a multi-project, and right now I have a structure that resembles this (actually there are a couple of jar projects and a couple of war projects)

```
/myProj
 |_______projA (jar)
 |          |____pom.xml
 |          |____target/jar files
 |_______projB (war)
 |          |___pom.xml
 |          |___web-inf/lib/jarfiles
 |_______projEar 
 |          |___pom.xml
 |___pom.xml
```

What I want to achieve, is to make `projA` and `projB` to read their dependences from a common shared folder, instead of keeping their own copy.

Actually, I don't really care where they read them from at compile time, but when I package my EAR file, I want each `jar`/`war` to appear just once, hence reducing the EAR size.

I've tried declaring the dependencies on the parent pom, declaring the dependencies as  and some other things, but so far I haven't achieved this.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Any simple maven plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding the JAR as a dependency to your EAR's pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

...and specifying the dependency as provided in your WARs' pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

*If Maven/other tooling has already copied the JAR to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory, you may need to delete the file manually prior to rebuilding.*

This should result in an EAR of the form:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
lib/myapp-utils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
META-INF/application.xml
myapp-web.war
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are moving to Maven, you should not store the dependency JAR's in your code base.  I would suggest you to create a central Maven repository which will contain all the dependencies.

Refer [mvn install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) to first install these artifacts into the local repository. Also, you can refer to the [maven central repository](http://www.repo1.maven.org) to get artifacts while building.

What you need to do is: remove all the dependency jar's from the source code, and all their dependency in the `pom.xml`. These would be downloaded and packaged from the maven central repository as and when required. Set the [Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) of the artifacts accordingly.